# js function for polyline on gmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

By calling my function drawGmapLine() my browser says "line.setMap is not a function".
My map is created without any problems. Can you see the problem?

```
function drawGmapLine(id) {
    var map =  $("#map");

    var pfad = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
            new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
            new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
            new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
        ];

        var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: pfad,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });

        line.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: You syntax near `var map = $gmap; new ...` is totally borked; that might be your problem.

Comment: but without that line I've the same problem. In that case I set line.setMap($gmap);

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code over correctly?

Comment: Yes - i am. Maybe this link helps to understand the problem. http://gmap.nurtext.de/js/jquery.gmap-1.1.0.js It's the class with the basic code of how I create a map. I call the function $("#map").gMap({  
markers: [
...
]});

Comment: The code you have posted contains a syntax error.  It looks like there is supposed to be an array of google.maps.LatLng objects, but the start of the declaration is missing (var pfad = [).  Please fix your posted code.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin you're using (jQuery GMap) uses Maps V2. Your code above is written using Maps V3. You need to find an updated plugin or use the Maps V3 API directly in order for the `new google.maps.Polyline()` call to work.

Comment: you were right. There was a copy mistake. But the code isn't working in that way too... I corrected the code in my post.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to get a reference to a google.maps.Map object.

```
var map =  $("#map");
```

So this won't work:

```
line.setMap(map);
```

The usual solution is to keep a reference to the map from when you construct it.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(...);
```

Comment: But I already have a map on which I would like to place the polyline. Your code would create a new map / reference.

Comment: I am making a suggestion about keeping a reference to your existing map, not creating a new one.  You didn't include any of the code you use to create the map in your question, so I couldn't reference that.  If you want a complete solution, post a link, a jsfiddle or complete code to reproduce the problem.